# Android button id

Tags: android

If I have created a button in xml and i want to use this button multiple times but give them unique id's, how do i do that? I don't know how many buttons i will have, so i can't create a number of buttons in my xml-file. I want to be able to change the buttons id while running the program. I've tried to do button.setId() but then everything breaks and wont work.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an independent button.xml file (or even do it as a style), then inflate that in your code as needed.

For instance, let's say you have an array of strings representing a list of countries, and you want a button for each country.  This is nice because if you add or remove any, you only have to modify the array, not your xml or the for loop.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
String[] countries = {"US", "Canada", "UK", "Australia"};
String country;
// Don't forget to add the following layout to your xml. 
LinearLayout buttonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);  
buttonLayout.removeAllViews();
for (int i = 0; i < countries.length(); i++) {
    country = countries.getString(i);
    Button temp = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.button);
    // Don't forget that id is an int, not a string.
    button.setId(id);
    button.setText(country);
    buttonLayout.addView(temp);
}
```

Bonus: you can also include this button in another xml file, and update the id in the include statement as follows:

```
<include layout="@layout/button" 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
/>
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer if the OP doesn't want to create the btn's dynamically

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear, but I think you can use dynamic button creation.

```
Button button = new Button();
// init it here

layout.add(button, new LayoutParams(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

give id in xml like

```
<Button android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/title_close" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are not sure of the instances you need in your application of a certain widget, then go for dynamic creation.
XML is mostly for static creation.